# Infinite Loop When Using Hooks in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've looked at a few other questions that are similar to this one but I can't really wrap my head around the solutions, I just started learning react yesterday. From the answers I've seen it sounds like I should change something with the way I use set but I don't know how to implement it.

I'm using hooks to wait for a promise to be fulfilled so that I can update text on a webpage. For some reason, the functions loop.

This is the way I'm using the hooks to update the webpage,

```
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("Loading...");

  geoCode.getAddress("43.6532", "-79.3832").then(res => {
    setAddress(res);
    console.log(res);
  });

  const [server, setServer] = useState({
    fulfilled: false,
    lat: "Loading...",
    lng: "Loading..."
  });

  const serverLoc = "Toronto";
  geoCode.getLatLng(serverLoc).then(res => {
    setServer({
      fulfilled: true,
      lat: res.lat,
      lng: res.lng
    });
  });

  const [recipient, setRecipient] = useState({
    fulfilled: false,
    lat: "Loading...",
    lng: "Loading..."
  });

  const recipientLoc = "Ottawa";
  geoCode.getLatLng(serverLoc).then(res => {
    setRecipient({
      fulfilled: true,
      lat: res.lat,
      lng: res.lng
    });
  });

  const [deliveryData, setDeliveryData] = useState({
    distance: "Loading...",
    duration: "Loading..."
  });

  if (server.fulfilled && recipient.fulfilled) {
    geoCode.getDistanceFromAddress(serverLoc, recipientLoc).then(res => {
      setDeliveryData({
        distance: res.distance,
        duration: res.duration
      });
    });
  }
```

Then in the return statement for the render I call them like this,

```
<h3>
  Lat: {server.lat} Lng: {server.lng}
</h3>
<h3>
  Lat: {recipient.lat} Lng: {recipient.lng}
</h3>
<h3>
  Distance: {deliveryData.distance} Duration: {deliveryData.duration}
</h3>
```

The geoCode.getLatLng and geoCode.getAddress keep looping and I'm not sure as to how to fix it. I would assume geoCode.getDistanceFromAddress is looping too but I wasn't logging it at the time and I've just used a paid API key like 2000 times and don't want to test it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are triggering async actions and setting state directly in render, instead you must use useEffect to so with appropriate dependency

```
const [address, setAddress] = useState("Loading...");


  const [server, setServer] = useState({
    fulfilled: false,
    lat: "Loading...",
    lng: "Loading..."
  });


  const [recipient, setRecipient] = useState({
    fulfilled: false,
    lat: "Loading...",
    lng: "Loading..."
  });

  useEffect(() => {
      geoCode.getAddress("43.6532", "-79.3832").then(res => {
        setAddress(res);
        console.log(res);
      });

        const serverLoc = "Toronto";
     geoCode.getLatLng(serverLoc).then(res => {
       setServer({
           fulfilled: true,
           lat: res.lat,
            lng: res.lng
       });
     });

      const recipientLoc = "Ottawa";
      geoCode.getLatLng(serverLoc).then(res => {
        setRecipient({
          fulfilled: true,
          lat: res.lat,
          lng: res.lng
        });
      });

  }, []); // empty dependency here



  const [deliveryData, setDeliveryData] = useState({
    distance: "Loading...",
    duration: "Loading..."
  });

    useEffect(() => {

      if (server.fulfilled && recipient.fulfilled) {
        geoCode.getDistanceFromAddress(serverLoc, recipientLoc).then(res => {
          setDeliveryData({
            distance: res.distance,
            duration: res.duration
          });
        });
      }
    }, [server, recipient]); // server and recipient here
```

Comment: Perfect this works thank you. From the documentation I just read I kind of understand what `[server, recipient]` is doing. The only question I have with it is, do I still need the if statement in that block? I get that it will rerun if either of those two things change, but does it also mean it will **only** run once those two are populated?

Comment: Yes, you'll still need the if statement since you only want to invoke `geoCode.getDistanceFromAddress` and update state when **both** values are truthy as the effect will run when either dependencies update.

Comment: @LewisH Yes you need both the two dependencies and an if condition because both server and recipient are fetched asynchrounously and hence the useEffect will get triggered when both of them change individually

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that this functions runs every time app renders(since you are setting state inside the function which re renders)

```
if (server.fulfilled && recipient.fulfilled) {
    geoCode.getDistanceFromAddress(serverLoc, recipientLoc).then(res => {
      setDeliveryData({
        distance: res.distance,
        duration: res.duration
      });
    });
  }
```